# Spark Session With Multiple s3 Roles

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, assume-role

I have a Spark job that reads files from an s3 bucket, formats them, and places them in another s3 bucket. I'm using the (SparkSession) spark.read.csv and spark.write.csv functionality to accomplish this

When I read the files, I need to use one IAM role (assume role), and when I write the files,  need to drop the assumed role and revert to my default role.

Is this possible within the same spark session?
And if not, is there another way to do this?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the S3A connector in Hadoop 2.8+, the S3A connector supports per-bucket settings, so you have different login options for different buckets

At some point (maybe around then, very much by hadoop 3) the AssumedRoleCredentialProvider takes a set of full credentials and calls AssumeRole for a given role ARN, so interacts with s3 under that role instead.

should be matter of

1. Make sure your hadoop-jars are recent
2. set the base settings with your full login
3. per bucket setting for the source bucket to use the assumed role credential provider with the chosen arn
4. make sure things work from the hadoop command line before trying to get submitted jobs to work.
5. then submit the job.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really answer my question. There's an array of possible buckets I could be reading from and writing to. What I need are two SparkContexts; one with one set of AWS credentials, and another with the assumed role I've given it.

Comment: doesn't work that way. Look at the per bucket settings and see what you can do. Hadoop 3.3+ delegation tokens would also let you collect session credentials for buckets using your local login, while all other buckets would use the default IAM role of the EC2 VM

Comment: @ehlJay to deal with an arbitrary input and output bucket, you could configure the per-bucket settings at runtime by setting the properties on the spark context hadoopConfiguration(). Your options for credential provider depend on with version of hadoop is being used by spark. hadoop 3.2 has a proper AssumedRoleCredentialProvider. For 2.9 (possibly 2.8), you can use the TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider by gathering the assumed role credentials before running.